# Title of UINavigationBar becomes blank when segueing back to root VC

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I've got a `UINavigationController` that segues to 2 other VC's. Whenever it reaches a certain VC with the current setup :

```
 // set text 
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];
 self.title = @"Title";

// make the nav bar transaparent
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setOpaque:NO];

// set white status bar
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];

//self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(16, 31, 22, 20)];
UIImage *backImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backButtonDetail"];
[backButton setBackgroundImage:backImage  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(popBack) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *backButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButtonItem;
```

And I pop the VC, the title of the root vc becomes empty. However, whenever I'm segueing to a VC without this setup, but a more 'basic' setup, the title stays where it should.

Comment: in viewWillAppear write  self.title = @"Title";

Comment: Try putting self.title in viewDidAppear

Answer (score -1):

Easiest thing I can recommend: use `[UINavigationBar appearance]` to set many of these customizations from the AppDelegate

Checkout out [AppCoda's post](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/) on the subject. I've just run through it myself and it's pretty great